# Javascript: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript

Something weird and I don't understand.

My code:

```
$("#loadbtn").click(function(e) {
    $html = '<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> dsfdsf';
    $("#content").html($html);
});
```

When I run the page on browser, it returns error saying `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`. I can't see anything wrong. Can you tell me what's wrong there?

Thank you.

Comment: is your $html var defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`</script>` always throws strange errors in javascript as it actually closes the current script, even when in a string, try splitting it up

```
$html = '<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></scr'+'ipt> dsfdsf';
```

Comment: Another common one you see is `<\/script>`, which JavaScript sees as `</script>` but the browser doesn't. Or better yet, of course, put the code in a separate `.js` file. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - or create script elements, and insert them into the head.

Comment: @ adeneo: True, but the general case is that that code would be absolutely fine, if it weren't *itself* between `<script>` / `</script>` tags. E.g., if it were in an external `.js` file, it would be fine and work as desired. You only have to worry about `</script>` with code directly contained by a script tag, rather than in a file referenced from one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Indeed, the issue is only with code that is itself in script tags, but often you see scripts added this way at the end of the DOM, for instance Google stuff etc. to defer loading. That's not the case here, as it's added on a click with jQuery, so moving the event handler to a seperate file would be preferable.